# Multivariable Joint Probability

Tags: probability

Say I have these events $A_1,A_2,A_3,...,A_n$. Where Event $A_2$ is affected by the events of $A_1$, and the event $A_3$ is affected by the event $A_2$ and so on and so forth. For example, you can think of the Event $A$ as the probability of drawing a red ball out of an urn without replacement sequentially

The joint probability of observing all these events (observing the sample)

$$p(A_1,A_2,..A_n) = p(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)p(A_3|A_1,A_2)\cdot \cdot \cdot P(A_n|A_1,A_2,...,A_{n-1}) \tag 1$$

This is Bayes Theorem rewritten differently.

**My Question:**  What if the events are not sequential? And it occured simultaneous and one event did not depend on the other event, can I still say? (I understand that independence would remove the conditionals but does this expression as it stand still hold?)

$$p(A_1,A_2,..A_n) = p(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)p(A_3|A_1,A_2)\cdot \cdot \cdot P(A_n|A_1,A_2,...,A_{n-1}) \tag 1$$

Can I rearrange the order of the events and go backwords?

$$p(A_1,A_2,..A_n) = p(A_n)P(A_{n-1}|A_{n})p(A_{n-2}|A_{n},A_{n-1})\cdot \cdot \cdot P(A_1|A_{n-1},A_2,...,A_{1}) \tag 1$$

Comment: You can do this. But usually this is very useful in dealing with experiments that are sequential in nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bayes Theorem does not depend on the physical interpretation of events (so in particular, the property of some events being sequential in time doesn't matter). It's always valid to write

$$P(A_1, A_2, \cdots, A_n) = P(A_n)P(A_{n-1}|A_n) \cdots P(A_1 | A_{n-1}, A_{n-2}, \cdots, A_1)$$

and furthermore, you can take them to be in any order. For example,
$$P(A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4) = P(A_2)P(A_3|A_2)P(A_1|A_2, A_3)P(A_4|A_1, A_2, A_3)$$

It's possible that the sequential interpretation of events lends itself to a natural writing of Bayes Theorem in some specific order. But it's always the case that you can write this product of conditional probabilities in any order and achieve the same joint probability (it just might not be useful, or may be difficult to compute).